# Alternative barrier to spinlock?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Lets say I have this function that multiple threads need to run in a sort of lock step

```
std::atomic<bool> go = false;  

void func() {
        while (!go.load()) {} //sync barrier
        ...
}
```

I want to get rid of the spinlock and replace it for something mutex based since I have a lot of threads doing all kinds of stuff and spinlocking a dozen of threads is disasterous to the overall throughput, it runs much quicker if I include Sleep(1) inside the spinlock for example.

So is there something in STL that would be similar to AllMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync() in HLSL for example? Basically it would just put each of the threads to sleep at the barrier until all of them have reached it.

Comment: For what it's worth, `while(!go.load())` can be written `while(!go)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do *exactly* what a condition variable is good for.

```
bool go = false;
std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;

void thread_func()
{
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        cv.wait(lock, []{ return go; });
    }
    // Do stuff
}

void start_all()
{
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        go = true;
    }
    cv.notify_all();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you are willing to use experimental features, then [`latch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/latch) or [`barrier`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/barrier) will help you. Otherwise you might create your own similar construct using [`conditional_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) or [`conditional_variable_any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable_any) with `shared_lock` (C++17 feature).

Using `shared_mutex` to implement a barrier:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <shared_mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

std::shared_mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable_any cv;
bool ready = false;

void thread_func()
{
    {
        std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(mtx);
        cv.wait(lock, []{return ready;});
    }
    std::cout << '0';
    //Rest of calculations
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        threads.emplace_back(thread_func);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(mtx);
        std::cout << "Go\n";
        ready = true;
    }
    cv.notify_all();
    for(auto& t: threads)
        t.join();
    std::cout << "\nFinished\n";
}
```